# How to use a variable in pgSQL function when executing sql?

Tags: database, postgresql, variables

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION drop_table(varchar) RETURNS VOID AS $$
DECLARE
  tablename ALIAS FOR $1;
  counter integer;
BEGIN
  --compute the counter variable, then continue:
  IF counter > 0 THEN EXECUTE 'DROP TABLE tablename'; --TODO: how to use variable here?
  END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

How can I use the variable `tablename` inside the `EXECUTE` statement? Currently the sql will use the name "tablename" instead of the given parameter of the function.

Comment: where you're assigning value for variable `counter`  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [format()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-QUOTE-LITERAL-EXAMPLE) in PostgreSQL

As Per Documentation :

> Format a string. This function is similar to the C function sprintf;
>   but only the following conversion specifications are recognized: %s
>   interpolates the corresponding argument as a string; %I escapes its
>   argument as an SQL identifier; %L escapes its argument as an SQL
>   literal; %% outputs a literal %. A conversion can reference an
>   explicit parameter position by preceding the conversion specifier with
>   n$, where n is the argument position.

```
select format('Hello %s','World')
```

result

```
format
text
---------------
Hello World
```

so your function should be :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION drop_table(varchar) RETURNS VOID AS $$
DECLARE
  tablename ALIAS FOR $1;
  counter integer;
BEGIN
  --compute the counter variable, then continue:
  IF counter > 0 THEN 
  EXECUTE  format('DROP TABLE %s',tablename); -- or you can directly give argument here ie format('DROP TABLE %s',$1)
  END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```